# Can I use cy.session() without calling cy.visit()?

Tags: cypress, session-cookies

I'm new to Cypress, so apologies, if the question is inadequate. Short description of the workflow that I'm trying to achieve:

```js
    describe('user selects products and navigates away from page', () => {
      //1
      it('user logs in and selects products', () => {
})
      //2
      it('user proceeds to compare selected products'), => {
})
      //3
      it ('user navigates away from comparison page, then back to comparison'), => {
})  
    })
```

This is what the login function looks like:

```js
    Cypress.Commands.add("openAndLogin", () => {
        cy.session('login', () => {
            cy.VisitHomePage()
            cy.get('#siteHeaderTopRight').find('button.signin-btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign In').click() 
            cy.userLogin()
        })
})
```

The first it-block runs fine, but the 2nd throws an error because I get stuck at some cy.session related intermittent screen and can't get to the user's product selection. I also can't use cy.visit() in the 2nd block.

So my question here is this: is it possible to use cy.session() if you're moving between pages that are dependent on your actions on the previous page? I can't call cy.visit() in each it-block in this scenario, can I?

I read somewhere that each it-block should be able to run independently, but putting the whole flow in a single it-block somehow doesn't seem right, either. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, each test (it block) should be independent of each other. Thus you'll have test set up in the befor/beforEach blocks. Once you test one section of UI in the app, you don't want to test it again so making API calls to set up your test is faster and makes them independent.

Comment: @jjhelguero so, does this mean then that I have to combine all 3 it-blocks from the scenario above into 1? since I can't call cy.visit() on an unknown location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you wrap in a `cy.session()` is cached for the duration of the run.

That means when you call `cy.openAndLogin()` the first time it does all the stuff inside and caches the resulting cookies, storage, etc.

The second time you call it, it does not repeat the code, but restores all the cached values.

The key thing is, each test should make a call to `cy.openAndLogin()`.

Try adding a `console.log()` inside the session code, it should only show once.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("openAndLogin", () => {
  cy.session('login', () => {

    console.log('Calling sign-in')

    cy.VisitHomePage()
    cy.get('#siteHeaderTopRight').find('button.signin-btn')
      .should('contain.text', 'Sign In').click() 
    cy.userLogin()
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have cy.session() in beforeEach(), so it runs before each test. But test #2 fails because of  this error: "this is a blank page.
We always navigate you here after cy.session()
To continue your test, follow up the command with cy.visit()
1 |
2 | cy.session(...)
3 | cy.visit(...)
4 |. I can't use cy.visit(), because in test #1 I'm selecting some products and test #2 is based on that selection.

Comment: Yeah, `cy.session()` only caches the cookies, localstorage, browser session store. But not the location. You will need to visit the correct URL each test, so test1 `cy.visit('/')`, test2 `cy.visit('/products/1')`, test3 `cy.visit('/comparison')`. It's based on the idea of SPA using a router with the product id embedded in the URL. But if your app does not do that I don't think you can use `cy.session()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this, afterEach test get your url and then in each test make cy.visit(new url)

```
cy.location().then((url) => {
            url = url.href
        })
```